# application-profile.yml does not pickup properties from main application.yml

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application with different environments. I have a main application.yml with a set of properties and an application-test.yml for my test environment.

Inside my application.yml, I have the following config

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: false
    user: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog-master.yaml
```

And inside my application-test.yml, I have the following

```
spring
  liquibase:
      user: sa
      password: password
```

I was expecting my test environment to use `liquibase.user` and `liquibase.password` from the `application-test.yml` and pick the two other sub-properties (`liquibase.enabled` and `liquibase.change-log`) from `application.yml`. My reasoning was that in my test environment, the Application context would pick up all the properties in `application.yml` and then overwrite only the subkeys defined in `application-test.yml`, while keeping the original values of `application.yml` if not explicitly overwritten.

But that does not seem to be the case; it looks as if the key `liquibase` in my `application-test.yml` overwrites all the key and subkeys of the `liquibase` defined in application.yml.
Therefore since in my `application-test.yml`, `liquibase.enabled` and `liquibase.change-log` are not defined; the test environment does not know about these values. I was expecting them to be picked up from the main `application.yml` instead. I tried to define them manually in my `application-test.yml` and my tests work fine. If I remove them, my tests fail because they use the default properties for liquibase instead of `liquibase.enabled: false` and `liquibase.change-log: classpath:db/changelog-master.yaml`

What I would like to do is the following:
In my main `application.yml`, have

```
main_key:
    sub_key_1: value_1
    sub_key_2: value_2
    sub_key_3: value_3
```

And in my `application-test.yml`, have only

```
main_key:
    sub_key_1: test_value_1
```

- have my test environment pickup `sub_key_2: value_2` and `sub_key_3: value_3` directly from `application.yml`, without them being overwritten by nothing in my test environment (since they are not defined in my application-test.yml)

Is it possible to have think kind of logic : if `main_key.sub_key_2` is defined in `application-test.yml` is defined, then use it, otherwise use the `main_key.sub_key_2` defined in `application.yml` ?
I feel that if I don't define all the `sub_keys` of my `main_key` in my `application-test.yml`, it is not possible to do it.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think I know why it does not work.

I had an empty `application.yml` inside my `test/resources/application.yml`. So I believe spring boot picks up the `test/resources/application.yml` instead of the `src/main/resources/application.yml` when `test/resources/application.yml` exists.

Which explains why the properties in my `src/main/resources/application.yml` were not picked up at all.

The solution was simply to delete the `test/resources/application.yml`